# Array of string pairs

Tags: c#, arrays

How  do I generate the array of string pairs?
I need it to quickly initialize it with static data.

```
stringPair[] arr = {{"hgh","hjhjh"},{"jkjk","kjhk"}
```

Comment: Do you want a 1-d or 2-d array?

Comment: Is stringPair a type that you have defined?

Comment: Are there unique keys? If so, a `Dictionary<string,string>` is appropriate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this using mulitdimentional array:

```
string[,] arr = new string[,]{{"hgh","hjhjh"},{"jkjk","kjhk"}};
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use list/array [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Class

Example

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> data = new List<Tuple<string, string>>{
        new Tuple<string, string>("Hello", "World"),
        new Tuple<string, string>("Foo", "Bar")
    };
```

As per @Eric Lippert's comment, Use `Tuple.Create`

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> data = new List<Tuple<string, string>>{
        Tuple.Create("Hello", "World"),
        Tuple.Create("Foo", "Bar")
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var arr = new[] { new[] { "hgh", "hjhjh" }, new[] { "jkjk", "kjhk" } };
```

This will initialize a `System.String[][]` jagged array.

Answer (score -1):

Use an `ArrayList<String, String>`

You can simply put as much info as you like in a data structure like this